# Calculating global sections of sheaves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Consider the usual projective space $\mathbb{P}^{1} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$, and the Weil divisor $D = \{0\} \subset \mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{P}^{1}$. Writing projective space as the union of the open sets, we obtain $\mathbb{P}^{1} = U_{0} \cup U_{1}$, using $U_{0} = Spec(\mathbb{C}[t]), U_{1} = Spec(\mathbb{C}[t^{-1}])$, we get $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{P}^{1}) = \mathbb{C}(t)$.

Defining $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^{1},O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(D))=\{f\in \mathbb{C}(t)^{*} | div(f) + D \geq 0\} \cup \{0 \}$, it is then claimed that it follows easily that the global sections are $1,t^{-1} \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^{1},O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}} (D))$ (cf. Introduction to Toric Varieties Cox, Little, and Schenck p. 247).

In addition, he further states that multiplying by $f$ gives a sheaf homomorphism $O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(-D) \to O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}$ and that doing this for $1, t^{-1} \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^{1},O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}} (D))$ gives $$O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(-D) \oplus O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(-D) \to O_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}$$

Could someone please explain these implications in detail? I am rather new to sheaf theory and am having trouble following the arguments in this example. I know that we define $div(f) = \sum \nu_{D}(f) D_{f}$, where $\nu$ is the valuation, but I still fail to see above implication.

Thanks

Comment: Given a particular $f \in \mathbb{C}(t)^\ast$, say $f = \dfrac{t^2 - 3t + 2}{t + 4}$, can you calculate $\operatorname{div}(f)$?

Comment: How would you do that? I'm not sure what the valuation would be exactly. Wouldn't it be the summation of the valuation times the divisor?

Comment: In this case, would $div(f)$ simply be $div(f) = \{2\} + \{1\} - \{4\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global sections $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(D))$ are, by definition, the rational functions $f(t) \in \mathbb{C}(t)$ which have at worst a simple pole at $t=0$ and are regular elsewhere, so we can write
$$
f(t) = [\textrm{global regular function}] + \frac{1}{t} [\textrm{global regular function}].
$$
However, the global regular functions on $\mathbb{P}^1$ are precisely the constants, so $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(D))$ is a 2-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with basis $\{ 1 , t^{-1} \}$.

This is in stark contrast to the global sections of $\mathcal{O}(-D)$; these are the rational functions $g(t) \in \mathbb{C}(t)$ which have a simple zero at least a simple zero at $t=0$ are regular elsewhere. In particular, such a function is everywhere regular, hence constant. The only constant function that satisfies this criteria is the zero function, so $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(-D)) = 0$.

Knowing this, can you describe the morphism $\mathcal{O}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}$?

**Edit 1**: Here is a more careful calculation of the global sections $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(D))$.

A global section $s \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(D))$ consists of 2 pieces of data: a section $s|_{U_0} = f_0 \in \Gamma(U_0, \mathcal{O}(D))$ and a section $s|_{U_1} = f_1 \in \Gamma(U_1 , \mathcal{O}(D))$ which agree on the intersection $U_0 \cap U_1$. Since $0 \in U_0$, $f_0$ is a rational function in $t$ with a pole (of order at most $1$) at $t=0$. Since $0 \not\in U_1$, $f_1$ is just a polynomial in $t^{-1}$, with no specified zeros (though it could have some). The compatibility condition is precisely that $s|_{U_0 \cap U_1} = f_0(t) = f_1(t^{-1})$ on $U_0 \cap U_1$, which can only occur if $f_0(t) = a + \frac{b}{t}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. Therefore, the section $s$ is given by $a+ \frac{b}{t}$.

**Edit 2**: Let's describe the morphism $\mathcal{O}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}$ on each piece of the open cover $\mathbb{P}^1 = U_0 \cup U_1$.

On $U_0$, the sections of $\mathcal{O}(-D)$ are $\Gamma(U_0, \mathcal{O}(-D)) = t \cdot \mathbb{C}[t]$, i.e. it consists of those polynomials $g(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ with (at least) a simple zero at $t=0$. If $f $ is either $1$ or $t^{-1}$, then the multiplication map $\Gamma(U_0, \mathcal{O}(-D)) \to \Gamma(U_0, \mathcal{O}) = \mathbb{C}[t]$ given by $g \mapsto gf$ is indeed a homomorphism.

On $U_1$, the sections of $\mathcal{O}(-D)$ are $\Gamma(U_1, \mathcal{O}(-D)) = \mathbb{C}[t^{-1}]$, because the divisor $D$ imposes no conditions on $U_1$ since $0 \not\in U_1$. Therefore, the multiplication map $\Gamma(U_1,\mathcal{O}(-D)) \to \Gamma(U_1,\mathcal{O}) = \mathbb{C}[t^{-1}]$, again given by $g \mapsto gf$, is a homomorphism.

Comment: Just to verify, the condition on the rational functions $f(t)$ comes from the condition $(div(f) + D)|_{U} \geq 0$ right? So, for $t^{-1}$ one gets $div(t^{-1}) + \{0\} = -\{0\} + \{0\} = 0$? And the fact that the pole/zero has to be at $t = 0$ is due to the fact that our Weil divisor is $\{0\}$?


And the reason $f(t)$ has to be constant otherwise, and can't be a function such as $t$ is because by definition, a regular function has to be of the form $\phi = \frac{a_{p}}{f_{p}^{n_{p}}}$?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I can't see the morphism $\mathcal{O}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}$ though. Is it induced by the homomorphism of varieties which comes from multiplication by $f$? I am having trouble thinking of $\mathcal{O}$ itself, as opposed to $\mathcal{O}(U)$ which is clearly defined as a set of functions satisfying a condition.

Comment: For your first point, remember that a global section of $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(D))$ is a rational function $f(t)$ satisfying $\textrm{div}(f) + D \geq 0$. The divisor $D$ is zero at every point except zero, which means that $f$ cannot have a pole anywhere except (possibly) at zero. Moreover, at zero, the condition becomes $\nu_0(f) + 1 \geq 0$, where $\nu_0(f)$ is the order of the zero/pole of $f$ at $0$. The only rational functions that satisfy this are those which are regular everywhere except at $0$, where they are allowed to have (at worst) a pole of order 1.

Comment: In order to understand the morphism $\mathcal{O}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}$, try to understand it on each piece of the open cover $\{ U_0, U_1 \}$, i.e. what is $\mathcal{O}(-D)(U_0) \to \mathcal{O}(U_0)$? In this case you are dealing with more "concrete" objects.

Comment: Sorry, but with the divisor defined with $D = \{0\}$, why does this mean it is zero at every point except zero? Why can we not consider rational functions such as $t$? So, for $\mathcal{O}(-D)(U_{0}) \to \mathcal{O}(U_{0})$, wouldn't this be a map from $0$ to any regular function $f$ on $U_{0}$ (which is the set of prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[t]$). The domain is 0 since $\Gamma(U_{0},\mathcal{O}(-D)) = 0$ as you have shown. And these regular functions have to be constant since they have to satisfy $\nu_{0}(f) \geq 0$?

Comment: I wasn't being very detailed before about the computation of the global sections (which I think was causing confusion) so I've included it as an edit to the answer.

Comment: For the map, $\mathcal{O}(-D)(U_0)$ consists of polynomials in $t$ with a zero at $0$, so the map $\mathcal{O}(-D)(U_0) \to \mathcal{O}(U_0) \simeq \mathbb{C}[t]$ sends such a polynomial $g$ to $gf$, where $f$ is either $1$ or $t^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I understand your edit of having the sections being compatible on the intersection, but I still do not understand why the function can't be linear in t, thus having a zero at t. Why can't it be say, $at + b + \frac{c}{t}$? So in general, if we have the divisor $D = \{a\}$, then it is zero everywhere and has the value 1 at the point $\{a\}$? Okay, so then, $\mathcal{O}(-D)(U_{1})$ has to be 0 because you can't have polynomials in $t^{-1}$ satisfying the condition $\nu_{0}(f) - 1 = 0$? And hence the morphism $\mathcal{O}(-D) \to \mathcal{O}$ is just given by the homomorphism on $U_{0}$?

Comment: If it were linear in t, then wouldn't the condition with the valuation still hold? Thanks for your patience